# Nodes http request before an async.map

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express, httprequest

I'm facing issue to receive an array from a http request before using async.map to launch queries on them.

My server side controller code below (express 4) :

```
'use strict';
var _ = require('lodash');
var request = require('request');
var asynce = require('async');
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    function cleanip(str) {
        return str.replace("/", "%2F");
    }
    var myUrls = [];
    var IpBlockedForSpam = [];
    var list = ["127.0.0.1/32", "192.168.0.1/32"];
    for (var i in list) {
        myUrls.push("http://localhost:9000/myapi/ip/blockedForSpam/" + cleanip(list[i]));
    }
    asynce.map(myUrls, function (url, callback) {
        request(url, function (error, response, html) {
            var r = JSON.parse(html);
            for (var i in r) {
                IpBlockedForSpam.push(r[i]);
            }
            callback(error, html);
        });
    }, function (err, results) {
        res.jsonp(IpBlockedForSpam);
    });
};
```

This code work with var list as static.

What i want to achieive is to be able fill this variable using a http request like this :

```
 request("http://localhost:9000/myapi/ip", function(error, response, body) {
        //console.log(body);
        remotelist.push(JSON.parse(body));
});
```

Calling `http://localhost:9000/myapi/ip` return :

```
[
"127.0.0.1/32",
"192.168.0.1/32"
]
```

I tried many thing without results because most time, my async method is launched before my required http call request to retrieve list.

Another thing, is it possible to not use url like `http://localhost:9000/myapi/*` and use only `/myapi/*`

Thank you in advance for suggestions, maybe i am wrong with this method.

See you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the code inside the `request()` callback so that the `list` is obtained first and only when it has been retrieved run the rest of the code:

```
'use strict';
var _ = require('lodash');
var request = require('request');
var asynce = require('async');
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    function cleanip(str) {
        return str.replace("/", "%2F");
    }
    var myUrls = [];
    var IpBlockedForSpam = [];
    var list = ["127.0.0.1/32", "192.168.0.1/32"];
    request("http://localhost:9000/myapi/ip", function(error, response, body) {
        // add the IP address array retrieved from this request
        list = list.concat(JSON.parse(body));
        list.forEach(function(item, i) {
            myUrls.push("http://localhost:9000/myapi/ip/blockedForSpam/" + cleanip(item));
        });
        asynce.map(myUrls, function (url, callback) {
            request(url, function (error, response, html) {
                var r = JSON.parse(html);
                for (var i in r) {
                    IpBlockedForSpam.push(r[i]);
                }
                callback(error, html);
            });
        }, function (err, results) {
            res.jsonp(IpBlockedForSpam);
        });
    });
};
```

P.S. it is not considered a good practice to iterate arrays with `for (var i in r)` because that is a property iteration that will accidentially include any enumerable properties of the array, not just array items.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried to use this code and I have this error no : asynce.map(myUrls, function (url, callback) {
        ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: @Widy - I fixed a couple syntax errors in my code.  You should not be posting answers that are comments.  Answers should ONLY be answers.  You can always use the "edit" link in your question if you need to post more than will fit in a comment.  But on stackoverflow here, answers should ONLY be answers.  As far as I know, you cannot use relative or partial URLS in node.js because there is no "default" context that would tell node.js what the default domain is when it is not supplied.

Comment: Thank you ! I already found errors and it gave me a headake :) Thank you too for explanation about stackoverflow answers /comments usage, it will be useful for next times.For URLS, /myapi is hosted within same express server, that is why i thought i can use /myapi instead of full URL path.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now, below working code :

```
'use strict';
var _ = require('lodash');
var request = require('request');
var asynce = require('async');
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    function cleanip(str) {
        return str.replace("/", "%2F");
    }
    var myUrls = [];
    var IpBlockedForSpam = [];
    //var list = ["127.0.0.1/32", "192.168.0.1/32"];
    var list = [];
    request("http://localhost:9000/myapi/ip", function(error, response, body) {
        list = list.concat(JSON.parse(body));
        list.forEach(function(item, i) {
            myUrls.push("http://localhost:9000/myapi/ip/blockedForSpam/" + cleanip(item));
        });
        asynce.map(myUrls, function(url, callback) {
            request(url, function(error, response, html) {
                var r = JSON.parse(html);
                r.forEach(function(item, i) {
                    IpBlockedForSpam.push(r[i]);
                });
                callback(error, html);
            });
        }, function(err, results) {
            res.jsonp(IpBlockedForSpam);
        });
    });
};
```

Some brackets was not closed and `concact` instead of `concat` (it helped me to really understand this approach from now) :)

Last thing, is it possible to not use url like `http://localhost:9000/myapi/*` and use only `/myapi/*` ?

Thank you @jfriend00